# Is one allowed to post in her/his blog an answer to a question she/he asked?

Tags: discussion, policy, copyright

If someone asks here (in the main site) a question and is pleased with a particular answer he/she got, may it be posted in his/her blog without asking permission to the answerer?

Edit: One should post it with the proper *attribution*. (See comment below by Casebash).

Example: an inequality on p-adic valuation of binomial coefficients ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/binomial-coefficients-how-to-prove-an-inequality-on-the-p-adic-valuation)).

Comment: If you read the bottom of the page, all content posted is licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required

Comment: @Casebash: Why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @Casebash: I didn't write that explicitly, but I'm going to insert it in my question, because I would state the attribution, as always do.

Comment: @Robert: Because I didn't explain this in detail. Posting as an answer would have discouraged someone else from doing this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, yes, as long as you give proper attribution. What is meant by proper attribution? Well, from the equivalent [meta.stackoverflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611):

> So let me clarify what we mean by
>   attribution. If you republish this
>   content, we require that you:
>
> - Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> - Hyperlink directly to the
>     original question on the source site
>     (e.g.,
>     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> - Show the author names for every
>     question and answer Hyperlink each
>     author name directly back to their
>     user profile page on the source site
>     (e.g.,
>     https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink
>   must point directly to our domain, and
>   not use a tinyurl or any other form of
>   obfuscation or redirection.

Comment: Thanks!

I assume the author of the question should give a similar proper attribuition, if she/he republishes her/his question here for the first time.